# Providing JavaScript Configuration (Laravel config() style)

Tags: javascript, laravel, configuration

*This may be better suited on Stackoverflow, in which case, please let me know and I will move it over...*

## Background

Consider the following file structure:

```
/config
│   index.js
│   app.js
│   api.js
│   ...
```

The purpose of the above is to provide global configuration throughout a static frontend application, **including** within the webpack build configuration.

My original intention was to provide a global function called `config` which would behave much like the Laravel `config` function.

For example:

`config('app.name')` would return the `name` property from the `app.js` configuration file

Instead, my solution simply provides an object which is used like so:

- `config.app.name`
- `config.api.url`

## My Code

The way I am doing this is extremely simple:

**/config/index.js**

```
module.exports = {
    app: require('./app'),
    company: require('./company'),
    api: require('./api'),
    locales: require('./locales')
};
```

**/config/app.js**

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'Foobar',
    // etc...
};
```

**Example Usage**

```
import config from './config';

console.log(config.app.name);
```

## My Question

Whilst I am not bothered whether `/config` provides an object, or a function, I am unsure as to whether the solution I have put together is the cleanest way of achieving this...

I appreciate this question might be considered 'subjective' but does anyone have any alternative ways in which they would go about doing this?